# How can one show that the first term of the integral ''dominates''?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Fix $1<p<N$ and let $(u_n)\subseteq W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be a sequence satisfying the following:

- $u_n \to 0$ and $\nabla u_n \to 0$ pointwise almost everywhere,
- $u_n \to 0$ in $L_{loc}^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$.
- $\nabla u_n$ is bounded in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$

I am trying to show that for any $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ one has:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \lvert \nabla \left( \phi u_n \right)\rvert^p
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \lvert  \phi \rvert^p\lvert \nabla \left(u_n \right)\rvert^p + o(1).
$$
So far, I have only been able to obtain the following
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \left\vert \nabla(\phi u_n)\right\vert^p = \left(\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \lvert  \phi \rvert^p\lvert \nabla \left(u_n \right)\rvert^p\right]^{1/p}+ o(1)\right)^p.
\end{align*}

My intuition says that I should be able to finish the proof by using some generalization of the binomial theorem. If anyone can either point me in the right direction or provide a source that I can cite showing that this is true I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The function $x \mapsto x^p$ is convex. Thus,
$$(a+b)^p = (\frac{2\,a}2 + \frac{2\,b}2)^p
\le \frac12 \, (2\,a)^p + \frac12 \, (2\,b)^p = 2^{p-1}\,(a^p + b^p)$$
for all $a,b \ge 0$.

**Edit:** As noted by Quoka, this does not yield the desired result, but only an inequality involving the constant $2^{p-1}$.

Now, I think that your identity is not enough. Let us denote $a_n := [\int |\phi|^p \, |\nabla u_n|^p ]^{1/p}$. Then, $a_n$ might go to infinity. Let us, for simplicity, consider the case $p = 2$.
Then,
$$ (a_n + o(1))^2 = a_n^2 + 2 \, a_n \, o(1) + o(1)^2.$$
However, since $a_n$ might be unbounded, the second addend might no longer be $o(1)$.
To give a precise example:
$$(n + 1/n) ^2 = n^2 + 2 + 1/n^2 \ne n^2 + o(1).$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this helps with my inequality? Wouldn't this give the inequality with a factor of $2^{p-1}$?

Comment: @Quoka: Yes of course. However, it might not be possible to deduce your desired inequality, see the edit.

Comment: I added some assumptions that I forgot to notice when I first posted the question. Thank you for your input thus far.